# Countdown Timer is not showing in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript, I want to create a countdown timer with localStorage which starts from given time and end to 00:00:00, but it's not working, 
When I am running my code it is showing value "1506".

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            if (localStorage.getItem("counter")) {
                var CurrentTime = localStorage.getItem("counter");
            }
            else {
                var Hour = 3;
                var Minute = 25;
                var Second = 60;
                var CurrentTime = Hour.toString() + ":" + Minute.toString() + ":" + Second.toString();
            }


            function CountDown() {                                
                document.getElementById('lblDuration').innerHTML = CurrentTime;
                Second--;
                if (Second == -1) {
                    Second = 59;
                    Minute--;
                }
                if (Minute == -1) {
                    Minute = 59;
                    Hour--;
                }
                localStorage.setItem("counter", CurrentTime);
            }

            var interval = setInterval(function () { CountDown(); }, 1000);

    </script>
```

Comment: You never modify CurrentTime in your function `CountDown()`.

Comment: Hi @Gerald Schneider
Thanks for your comment, I didn't understand, please can you explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When localStorage is available you don set the values for Hour, Minute and Second. So when the countdown function executed it finds Second to be undefined and the statement Second-- converts Second to NaN.
To fix it just initialize the Hour, Minute and Second Variable.
I 've refactored your code  a little bit hope it helps:

```
function CountDown() { 
    var currentTime =  getCurrentTime();                           
    printCurrentTime(currentTime)
    currentTime.second--;
    if (currentTime.second == -1) {
        currentTime.second = 59;
        currentTime.minute--;
    }
    if (currentTime.minute == -1) {
        currentTime.minute = 59;
        currentTime.hour--;
    }
    setCurrentTime(currentTime);
}

  function setCurrentTime(newCurrentTime){
    if(localStorage) localStorage.setItem("counter", JSON.stringify(newCurrentTime));
    else setCurrentTime.storage = newCurrentTime;
  }
  function getCurrentTime(){
    var result = localStorage ? localStorage.getItem("counter") : setCurrentTime.storage;
    result = result || {hour:3, minute:25, second:60};
    if (typeof(result) === "string")result = JSON.parse(result);
    result.toString = function(){
        return result.hour +  ":" + result.minute + ":" + result.second;
    }
    return result;
  }
  function printCurrentTime(currentime){
        var domTag = document.getElementById('lblDuration');
        if(domTag) domTag.innerHTML = currentime.toString();
        else console.log(currentime);
  }
setInterval(function () { CountDown(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks @borja gomez
I run your code but it's showing output "1506"

Comment: That's strange I've run it on firefox IE and chrome without a problem. Where are you trying to run it?

Comment: I run it in chrome, but when you discussed about different browse, it worked successfully, but it is not stopping event after I close the browser ?
I want when I run the code again it should start again from it's default values
Please help

Comment: I've left a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wtzra540/). The only explanation I can find is that you have not cleaned the local storage before run it clean the local storage with localStorage.removeItem('counter')

Comment: It's stopping, but the problem is that it's keeping the values in the local storage so when you open again the window it starts where it left. If you want to start again don't use the local storage [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kyha2j98/) you'll find the same code without using local storage

Comment: I used localStorage.removeItem("counter");
but it's not working.
please can u edit that fiddle and make changes ?
please it'll be great help

Answer (score 2):

1. you need to declare variables `Hour, Minute, Second, CurrentTime` out side `if else` block. In this case they are not in `function CountDown()` scope.
2. you are not setting `CurrentTime = Hour.toString() + ":" + Minute.toString() + ":" + Second.toString();` after `localStorage.setItem("counter", CurrentTime);`

```js
var Hour = 3;
var Minute = 25;
var Second = 60;
var CurrentTime = Hour.toString() + ":" + Minute.toString() + ":" + Second.toString();


function CountDown() {
    document.getElementById('lblDuration').innerHTML = CurrentTime;
    Second--;
    if (Second == -1) {
        Second = 59;
        Minute--;
    }
    if (Minute == -1) {
        Minute = 59;
        Hour--;
    }
    CurrentTime = Hour.toString() + ":" + Minute.toString() + ":" + Second.toString();
}

setInterval(function () {
    CountDown();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="lblDuration"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @ozil
Thanks for your valuable comment, 
Your code is working fine but you removed the localStorage, which I want to put it to prevent my countdown  timer on page refresh,